# Redirección a bing, posible culpa de xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

Inicie xampp, al rato voy a buscar en Google una cosa y al abrir una pestaña nueva, me salta el buscador bing, al parecer existe un malware de que te hace usar bing.

Después me avisa chrome que 2 contraseñas de 127.0.0.0:10080 han sido vulneradas hace 8 minutos, concuerda desde que encendí xampp.

Apagué xampp y ahora funciona normal con Google.

La verdad es que estoy un poco rallado, no descargué ningún.exe ni nada de nada.

Estuve ayer modificando ficheros de xampp porque me daban conflictos, pero era MySQL, luego tenía el iis de Windows y lo quité porque no me dejaba usar xampp.

Ahora encendí otra vez xampp y funciona normal, nada raro.

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta? Saludos.

Comment: Es por si me pudieron hackear algo, o si tengo un virus en el ordenador. Estoy algo preocupado, aunque supongo que será cosa de xampp y no debería preocuparme no sé

Comment: Con respecto a las password vulneradas, eso es porque google en sus cambios recientes a Chrome "verifica" tus passwords y si son por ejemplo 12345, te dice que han sido vulneradas pero no se refiere a que te hayan hackeado, sino a que son muy débiles. Para deshabilitar el mensaje, ve a chrome://settings/syncSetup y busca la opción "Advertirme si quedan expuestas las contraseñas ante una violación de la seguridad de los datos". Saludos.

Comment: Lo de bing me suena raro, no tengo idea de que pueda ser. Saludos.

Comment: Las contraseñas si que eran muy fáciles, pudo ser por eso